# How to make R not consider my missing values as another level

Tags: r, anova, factors, levels

I have a data frame on which I am doing anova using three fixed independent factors of which one is gender which should have two levels 'male' and 'female', but some of the the data-points have missing values(blanks) for gender. 
Now the problem is R interpreted my gender as a factor having three levels of m, f and '' (i.e. blank level) and in the anova results showed that it had two degrees of freedom, instead of just one degree of freedom. How do I correct this?
I don't want to exclude those datapoints which don't have gender.
Can anyone point me in the right direction please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a contradiction: You don't want `NA` values as an additional level, but also don't want to exclude them. You can have only one of those. [Multiple imputation](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~jls/mifaq.html) might be an alternative.

Comment: I don't want to exclude those data points because except for missing gender values they have the values for the other fixed factors. So I don't want to lose out on that information.

Comment: Thanks Ronald. You are right, I had to exclude those datapoints.